# Python sending GET request to express server in electron main.js process error

Tags: javascript, python, express, electron

I am using the electron framework with a few helper python files. I am running into this error where it seems like I'm unable to start an express server in the main.js process for some reason.

Here is the error

```txt
Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::33333
    at __node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace (node:internal/errors:490:5)
    at __node_internal_uvExceptionWithHostPort (node:internal/errors:589:12)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1740:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1788:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1876:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\johndoe\stuff\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
    at main.js:18:10
```

Here is the main.js code that is starting the express server

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog} = require('electron')
const path = require('path');
const { electron } = require('process');
const $ = require('jquery');
const fs = require('fs');
const { Console } = require('console');

const express = require("express")
const expresso = express();
const port = 33333;

expresso.get('/invokeFunction', (req, res) => {
  myFunction(); // this is the function you want to invoke
  res.send('Function invoked!');
});

expresso.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

function myFunction() {
  console.log("Function in Electron's main.js has been triggered.");
}
```

and here is where I'm invoking this function from another file

```
# testing communication between processes
import requests

response = requests.get('http://localhost:33333/invokeFunction')
```

This port is 1000% not in use and I've checked it using netstat and ensured that connections were being closed when the program stopped running.

Comment: You might have previous node processes of main.js that are preventing you from using that port. Try running `tasklist` in CMD and look for any node.exe tasks, copy the PIDs, and run `tasklist /pid <pid here> /F` for each one